# jQuery - Simple Text Rotator with a href links

Tags: jquery, rotation

I am using Simple [Text Rotator](https://github.com/peachananr/simple-text-rotator) and its fantastic, my only issue I have with it is my text I am trying to rotate are links:

```
<h1 class="sliding-text">
    <span class="rotate">
        <a href="#link-1">Link 1</a>, 
        <a href="#link-2">Link 2</a>,
        <a href="link-3.php">Link 3</a>,
        <a href="link-4.php">Link 4</a>
    </span>
</h1>
```

but when I run my site, they are no longer links :(

Here is how I am adding the library to the sliding-text h1:

```
$(".sliding-text .rotate").textrotator({
    animation: "fade",
    speed: 1000
});
```

and here is the jquery code for the library:

```
!function ($) {

    var defaults = {
        animation: "fade",
        separator: ",",
        speed: 2000
    };

    $.fx.step.textShadowBlur = function (fx) {
        $(fx.elem).prop('textShadowBlur', fx.now).css({ textShadow: '0 0 ' + Math.floor(fx.now) + 'px black' });
    };

    $.fn.textrotator = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            var el = $(this)
            var array = [];
            $.each(el.text().split(settings.separator), function (key, value) {
                array.push(value);
            });
            el.text(array[0]);

            // animation option
            var rotate = function () {
                switch (settings.animation) {

                    case 'fade':
                        el.fadeOut(500, function () {
                            index = $.inArray(el.text(), array)
                            if ((index + 1) == array.length) index = -1
                            el.text(array[index + 1]).fadeIn(settings.speed);
                        });
                        break;
                }
            };
            setInterval(rotate, 8000);
        });
    }

}(window.jQuery);
```

as you can see the separator is the `,` which is what I have after each link, how come the link is not appearing? and is there anything I can do to add the links with text in the rotator ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the library is set up to only rotate using jQuery's .text() method.  As such, any extraneous HTML will be parsed out when the text array is built.  A few modifications to the library code will fix the problem for you.

```
  var el = $(this)
  var array = [];

  $.each(el.html().split(settings.separator), function(key, value) {
    array.push(value);
  });

  el.html(array[0]);
```

We switch the library's use of .text() here to .html().  This ensures that the HTML elements will be added to the array between the separators instead of just the inner text of the elements.

```
      var rotate = function() {
        switch (settings.animation) {
            case 'fade':
            el.fadeOut(500, function() {
              index = $.inArray(el.html(), array)
              if((index + 1) == array.length) index = -1
              el.html(array[index + 1]).fadeIn(settings.speed);
            });
          break;
        }
      };
```

We do essentially the same thing in the rotation function of the library.  Switch it to .html() so that the comparison still works, and so that the HTML in the array will fade in correctly.

For a working demo, refer to this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prcn4n5t/)